# Join with Concact to Create a Tuple Column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes and I need to do a join by the `external_id` field to get the `product_id` and to insert in the first dataframe according to the column `external_id`, the detail is that I need to create a tuple, because a column `external_id` can have more than one product.

That is, the expected output of this new column should be, for example: `(1, 2, 3)`

So I'll know that that `external_id` has more than one product.

Dataframe 1 - who will receive the join:

| id | external_id | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a43505 | Example | 1 |
| 2 | 11b737 | Example | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | Example | 1 |
| 4 | lb22 | Example | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | Example | 1 |

Dataframe 2 - Dimension:

| product_id | external_id | product_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a43505 | Product 1 |
| 2 | c911d8 | Product 2 |
| 3 | 11b737 | Product 3 |
| 4 | a43505 | Product 4 |
| 5 | 5b1381 | Product 5 |
| 6 | a43505 | Product 6 |

Expected:

| id | external_id | column1 | column2 | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a43505 | Example | 1 | (1, 4, 6) |
| 2 | 11b737 | Example | 1 | (3) |
| 3 | 5b1381 | Example | 1 | (5) |
| 4 | lb22 | Example | 1 | () |
| 5 | 2 | Example | 1 | () |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `map`:

```
df1["product_id"] = df1["external_id"].map(df2.groupby("external_id")["product_id"].agg(tuple))

>>> df1
   id external_id  column1   column2 product_id
0   1      a43505  Example         1  (1, 4, 6)
1   2      11b737  Example         1       (3,)
2   3           3  Example         1        NaN
3   4        lb22  Example         1        NaN
4   5           2  Example         1        NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way :

```
df_grp_dim = df_dim.groupby('external_id')['product_id'].aggregate(list)
out = df.join(df_grp_dim,on='external_id')
```

output:

```
>>>
   id external_id  column1   column2 product_id
0   1      a43505  Example         1  [1, 4, 6]
1   2      11b737  Example         1        [3]
2   3           3  Example         1        NaN
3   4        lb22  Example         1        NaN
4   5           2  Example         1        NaN
```

Comment: @not_speshal it is "created" by `join`  (NB. I would avoid overwriting `df_dimension` though and feed the groupby result directly to join)

Comment: @not_speshal no ,as mozway said, it exists in first df and by joining it brings all the columsn we want.

Comment: @eshirvana - My bad. I had the index named "id" instead of "product_id". :)